# How to kill all threads individually in their allocated run-time

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a program which asks how many villain objects are to be created. It then creates the subsequent threads, which run for a random number of ms before being killed. The program currently creates the threads correctly, however only the final thread created is being killed. How would I modify my code so that all threads are killed within the random time each are allocated?

I tried moving the try/catch declaration inside the for loop. While all threads were created and killed, it did so one after another; for instance, the next thread was not created until the one beforehand was killed which defeats the purpose.

```
    Villian villian = null;
    Random randomVillian = new Random();

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many villians would you like to create?");

    int amountOfVillians = input.nextInt();

    int time;

    Random threadTime = new Random();

    time = threadTime.nextInt(10000);

    if (amountOfVillians < 7) {

        for (int x = 0; x < amountOfVillians; x++) {

            int randomGenerator = randomVillian.nextInt(6);

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                    if (randomGenerator == 0 ) {

                        villian = new FlyingVillian();
                    }

                    else if (randomGenerator == 1) {

                        villian = new StrongVillian();
                    }

                    else if (randomGenerator == 2) {

                        villian = new FastVillian();
                    }

                    else if (randomGenerator == 3) {

                        villian = new SmartVillian();
                    }

                    else if (randomGenerator == 4) {

                        villian = new FireVillian();
                    }

                    else if (randomGenerator == 5) {

                        villian = new IceVillian();
                    }

                        try {

                            writeToFile(villian);
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {

                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

                VillianThreads temp = new VillianThreads(villian);
                temp.start();
                System.out.println(villian.getName() + " has entered the battlefield!");

                }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(time);
                System.out.println(villian.getName() + " has escaped!");

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

    else {

            System.out.println("Please enter a value of less than 7");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the time into the Thread's Runnable, here the Villian object, and have it kill "itself" after time is up.

Comment: I have done this, however the Villian objects are being created and killed one after another that is the issue. I would like them to be created at the same time and be killed within the random time they are given

Comment: Well yes, of course, since you're calling `Thread.sleep` in the calling code, a line of code which **blocks** the calling code. If you don't want this code blocked, then don't do this.